# Is there a way to poll a file handle returned from subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess

Say I write this:

```
from subprocessing import Popen, STDOUT, PIPE
p = Popen(["myproc"], stderr=STDOUT, stdout=PIPE)
```

Now if I do

```
line = p.stdout.readline()
```

my program waits until the subprocess outputs the next line.

Is there any magic I can do to `p.stdout` so that I could read the output if it's there, but just continue otherwise? I'm looking for something like `Queue.get_nowait()`

I know I can just create a thread for reading `p.stdout`, but let's assume I can't create new threads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `select` module in Python's standard library, see http://docs.python.org/library/select.html .  `select.select([p.stdout.fileno()], [], [], 0)` immediately returns a tuple whose items are three lists: the first one is going to be non-empty if there's something to read on that file descriptor.

Comment: What exactly is returned? This still doesn't give a clue how much bytes is there to read.

Comment: `select` returns the set of file descriptors (among those you passed it) on which I/O can be performed without blocking. If you can arrange for p.stdout to be set to non-blocking after the fact (system dependent) you can just p.stdout.read(N) for some large N and get all bytes that are in fact available; if the nonblocking option is not available, all you can do is read 1 byte at a time and go back to `select`ing until that tells you there are no more. Be sure to append the bytes you read into a list and ''.join it at the end (much faster than +='ng away on strings!-).

Comment: `select` should not work on windows with file descriptors according to docs in 2.x.

Comment: `from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT ; p=Popen(['python.exe'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, stdin=PIPE) ; select((p.stdout.fileno(),), (), (), 0)` produces `error: (10038, 'An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket')` because, as the python documentation says, select.select is implemented using WinSock's select, which only accepts sockets, not file descriptors.

Answer (score 8):

Use `p.stdout.read(1)` this will read character by character

And here is a full example:

```
import subprocess
import sys

process = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)

while True:
    out = process.stdout.read(1)
    if out == '' and process.poll() != None:
        break
    if out != '':
        sys.stdout.write(out)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  I don't know how many questions I've seen asking for a simple answer to this issue - this was it.  I'd been trying to read character by character too but I didn't know how to check if the process had finished....completely missed poll() - duh. +1

Comment: +1 this solution might be appropriate on Windows where `select` doesn't work on file descriptors created by `subprocess` module. Note: if the subprocess generates enough output on stderr then it might block unless you read from it (OP redirects stderr to stdout (`stderr=STDOUT`) so this won't happen). Use `is` to compare with `None` e.g., `if x is not None:`. You could use `if out:` instead of `if out != '':` (it works both for bytestrings and Unicode strings). Also if `cmd` uses block-buffering in non-interactive mode then `process.stdout` won't get anything until `cmd` flushes the buffer.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question that was asked.  This method blocks at the read(1) if there's no output available-- what was asked for was a method that does not block in that case, but instead goes on to do something else.

Comment: @DonHatch you're correct, but it was useful to me anyway