# How to send data from C++ to Python

Tags: python, c++

I have a program in C++ that computes some ints. I want to "send" those ints from C++ to Python in real time. As the program in C++ is computing the numbers, I want to read them in Python.

What would be the best way to do this? I have seen some options but they all seem very complicated.

Comment: The absolute simplest option IMO is to have your C++ program print its numbers to stdout, write a Python script that reads numbers from stdin, and pipe one to the other.  It depends on whether you want to have the two compiled into a single binary, whether you want them to be able to run on different machines, etc.

Comment: Some other options (which are indeed more complicated) are:  Use a socket to send the data from the C++ program to the Python program, or alternatively embed the Python interpreter in the C++ program and have the C++ program run the Python script that way, or make a library out of the C++ code and write a wrapper so that the Python script can call the C++ code via function calls.

Comment: There are some good examples here of what you want to do:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36748829/piping-binary-data-between-python-and-c

Comment: Thank you! Piping seems like the easiest way, I will try that